# React Hooks & useContext: Is This a Good Pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

I'm studying `useContext` with React Hooks. I would like to pass a single object containing application state to context Consumers, e.g.:

```
<AppContextProvider.Provider value={AppState}>
  {props.children}
</AppContextProvider.Provider>
```

Of course, I will need to pass some `getters` and `setters` to enable child components to update application state.

Is this pattern an efficient approach -- is there a better pattern?

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

function AppContextProvider(props) {
    const AppState = {
        aVideoCallIsLive: [get, set] = useState(false),
        channelName: [get, set] = useState(null),
        localVideoStream: [get, set] = useState(null),
        selectedBottomNavIndex: [get, set] = useState(-1),
        loginDialogIsOpen: [get, set] = useState(false),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a reducer and pass a single dispatch function?

I believe its also recommended you pass state and dispatch is separate contexts otherwise calling dispatch will cause everything inside the context to re render.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer